Multinomial Logit Extension
The derivation of the multinomial logit probabilities depends on the difference of two Type 1 extreme value (Gumbel) random variables following a logistic distribution. We say the unobserved utility follows a Gumbel distribution and get the result that

In context of random utility model, this tells us the probability that good j gives the highest utility for individual i.
My question is, what if there are many goods from different countries and we would like to find probability that the good that gives the highest utility is in a certain country, for example. What would this probability be? Can we use the fact that the maximum of n Gumbel draws is also Gumbel (e.g. Bury (1999)) to treat each country like a separate Gumbel draw and compare the maxes? I think that is what they do in this paper but I can't understand it at all: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=926133

There are similar questions on Economics Stack Exchange, maybe this question should be moved there, too.
